# How do I install kernel header files?

Tags: kernel, linux-headers

i want to write a device driver but not able to find the header file can someone please help me find them?Also if someone can point out some important site links that would be really appreciated

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You should be able to install the kernel header files for the currently running kernel by running the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

In general, the kernel header packages are named linux-header-* where "*" indicates the version & variant (generic, server, etc.).

Comment: hey  thanks but could you tell me what does *generic, server, etc* means i want to write (kernel driver)

Comment: This won't install the headers for future updates automatically and you'll have to re-run this command every time. Therefore, it's recommended to install the metapackage instead, as described in [another answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/268710/88802).

Comment: Note: this doesn't put them in the GCC include path, you still need `-I`.

Comment: Note: For this to work, the line appropriate `deb-src` line must be present in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: I'm sorry for it doesn't work at which the version of my kernel is 4.19.57-v7+. How come?

Answer (score 112):

You can just type:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

if you are on a Desktop installation. The apt-get will solve the dependencies and install the correct version of kernel headers.

Comment: and Ubuntu will also update them when a new version comes out

Comment: Or `linux-headers-virtual` if your running a VM in an Openstack instance...

Comment: In Debian Wheezy I get the error message _"Package linux-headers-generic is not available, but is referred to by another package. [...] E: Package 'linux-headers-generic' has no installation candidate"_

Comment: @IQAndreas the `linux-headers-generic` package is ubuntu specific. On Debian you should use `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: I have linux-headers-generic installed on 18.04 but still don't have the headers for the newest and current kernel version. Maybe it's just a bug with this version, I've compiled kernel modules in earlier versions so I must've had the correct headers back then.

Answer (score 20):

#### Case of Obsolete kernel package

This should cover another problem when: the currently running kernel is obsolete, meaning it's not in the repository anymore neither its headers. So the best thing to do is to update the kernel to last version in the repository.

`linux-generic` is a meta package to keep current version of **the kernel & its headers**:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

**Note:** Depending on your Ubuntu edition, See if you need `linux-lowlatency` (Ubuntu Studio), `linux-signed-generic` or `linux-virtual`.

Comment: None of the other solutions worked for me when trying to install a driver. Thanks you.

Comment: an almost equivalent for debian is called `linux-headers-amd64` (for amd64 systems, obviously)

Comment: Amazing, `linux-headers-amd64` did the job for me for my Gitlab pipelines! The `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` did not work though. Voting up.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have aptitude installed:  `sudo aptitude install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Essentially the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

these commands should work:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
systemctl reboot
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get upgrade linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

for better instruction checkout this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXpaQNfmyJA&t=1s)

Comment: He is just asking how to install headers, why would you recommend upgrading the distribution? Do not follow these steps if you just want to download the headers.