# VMware on Ubuntu 15.10 - GNU C Compiler (gcc) version 4.9.2 was not found

Tags: vmware, 15.10

After I installed the lastest Ubuntu version, VMware didn't work. I just cliked and nothing.
After I tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH vmware` I got this error:

[image]

Also, I tried `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic` and it says everything's up to date and there's no update available.

And I tried `sudo /etc/init.d/vmware start` command and I got this:

[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: What does `gcc --version` say?

Comment: `gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.3-5ubuntu1) 4.9.3`

Comment: A newer version threw it off, I suppose. Try specifying `/usr/bin/gcc` for the location and then continuing the installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install kernel header files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files)

Comment: @muru I think there's duplicate. After I tried `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` I got: Package 'linux-headers-3.19.0-28-generic' has no installation candidate

Comment: I tried `/usr/bin/gcc` and I got this: gcc: fatal error: no input files / compilation terminated.

Comment: 15.10 uses a 4.X kernel. How do you have 3.19?

Comment: Yesterday I searched for this 'cause I didn't want to make a topic without me documenting.  I guess I tried some commands that change 5.1 to 4.9 or something like that.

Answer (score 9):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

then open your vmware & in 1st window and click Install, wait for about 7 mins & vmware will be open.

Answer (score 2):

For kernel 3.x version - install the package `gcc-4.9`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.9
```

For kernel 4.x version - install the package `gcc-5`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-5
```

---

To always have the latest version installed

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc
```

Comment: Thanks. That problem's gone, now new one's up. I get this error: http://i.imgur.com/mLbxEK6.png

Comment: Sorry, be fair, new problem means new question. =)

Comment: And the kernel in 15.10 is 4.x. Perhaps you should install `sudo apt-get install --reinstall  linux-generic  linux-headers-generic`, reboot and select kernel 4.x

Comment: Ok, not I get this error for 5.2.1 not for 4.9.2: http://i.imgur.com/VLdiS2c.png

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I tried that and I get `gcc-5 is already the newest version.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30717/discussion-between-a-b-and-lurrdock).

Comment: Specifying gcc-5 to apt explicitly solved the issue. Ubuntu 18.04, Kernel 4.20

Answer (score 2):

None of the other solutions here worked for me using Ubuntu 15.10 and vmware 12.1 pro, which was asking for gcc 4.9.2

The problem was caused by ld path (dynamic libs), and I needed to fix vmware as follows:

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar xvf vmnet.tar
cd vmnet-only
make
cd ..
tar xvf vmmon.tar
cd vmmon-only
make
cd ..
mkdir /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc
cp vmmon.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmmon.ko
cp vmnet.o /lib/modules/`uname -r`/misc/vmnet.ko
depmod -a
/etc/init.d/vmware restart
nano /usr/bin/vmware
```

add before `set -e` :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Save & exit and launch Vmware!

Complete thread here : https://communities.vmware.com/thread/521374

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
/usr/bin/gcc-5
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

**First open Console and type:**

```
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
```

**Then change current directory:**

```
cd vmware-host-modules
```

**Now checkout branch:**

```
git checkout player-16.0.0
```

*After this you have to compile it, install it and either restart or start vmware:*

Now type:

```
make
```

It's time to install compiled files:

```
sudo make install
```

Time to Start VMware:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware start
```

**Note:** *this worked for my Vmware 16 Player, i hope this would be helpful for you, keep in prayers Thank you!*

Answer (score 1):

I had this worked on ubuntu 22.04. This will match the vmware version you have with your current kernel.

```
wget https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/player-x.y.z.tar.gz
tar -xzf player-x.y.z.tar.gz
cd vmware-host-modules-workstation-x.y.z
make
sudo make install
```

Switch x,y,and z with the vmware version you have, e.g. mine is player-16.2.3. Then, restart your computer.