# Ubuntu 14.04 cannot download updates

Tags: 14.04, updates, dell

Ubuntu 14.04 will not update on my Dell Inspirson. I don't know what steps to take to resolve this on my own. I have already checked my system settings, software & updates and I check all sources except pre-release updates (trusty-proposed). The system updates the catch and I see updates being compiled but they always fail to download to my computer. I also tried checking the (trusty-proposed) update, with no further changes. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an IPv6 issue, the updates will just stall, try this to see if it helps..

[Something similar to this Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method)

> Add -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true when running apt-get.
>
> If you want to make the setting persistent just create /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4 and put Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true"; in it.

---

Running **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade** from the command line might give more clues to what's going on.

You could also try clearing the apt download directory with **sudo apt-get clean** and check you've adequate disk space.

Comment: This is what the system error reads  <br/>_E:The package linux-headers-3.13.0-76 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it._  <br/>I just don't know exactly where to find a trust-worthy source.  <br/>Any references?

Comment: Try this solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files

Comment: Thank you very much - but I did a new installation. I believe there where several issues I was unable to detect. Thanks again.